# remove element from std::list by reference

Tags: c++, reference, stdlist

```
std::list<Reader> readers;

readers.push_back(Reader());

Reader& r = *(readers.begin());

/* at this point, the exact place in list, where the reader was picked out, is forgotten. 
   Only 'r' shows which element of the list it is. */

readers.erase(r); //<---how to do this?
```

Clients get the new instances 'reader' objects from a manager/dispatcher. The manager maintains an internal list of whatever was dispatched and invalidates/frees up a cached data if "everyone interested" picked it up by observing the pool of readers dispatched.

When the client is no longer interested in the data, it should return the reader to the manager for removal from the pool. But I don't want the client to keep an iterator - it's absolutely uninterested in guts of the manager and the pool of the readers; only needs this one own reader it got, not an iterator pointing to it. So, for deletion, it calls the manager's cleanup function, with the reference to that single reader.

Is there a nicer way to erase that reader from the list than to iterate through the whole list in search of that one reader the reference leads to?

Comment: Are these `Readers` unique (no `Reader`s have the same value)?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Yes. One unique reader per client, with methods to pick data from cache (and mark it "used up by this one"), manager invalidates data if it's "used up" by all interested.

Comment: `readers.remove(r);` should work (if `r` is unique) but will internally iterate the list.

Comment: What about using `std::find` to locate the object first, then removing using the iterator?

Comment: I would reconsider keeping an iterator. It doesn't necessarily need to couple your clients with the implementation when you use generic constructs like `auto`.

Comment: @Galik: C++98, no 'auto'.  :-(    The iterator declaration for this (manager being a template class, per cached data type) is monstrous enough already.

Comment: @SF. Okay, well then I would be tempted to do something like `typedef std::list<Reader>::iterator reader_ref;` to decouple the clients from the implementation type. To be honest holding a literal reference `Reader&` to a transient object doesn't feel right to me, unless the reference is permanent for the lifetime of the object holding it?

Comment: @Galik: the only points where the list changes is when a client requests a new reader, or returns old reader for erasure. Since it's std::list and not vector, no other elements should are supposed to be affected. Also, manager *must* outlive all clients.

Comment: I just think your options are limited. A pointer can't know anything about what might contain the object it points to. The other option I can think of is to give the `Reader` information about where it is contained. But that's a stronger more invasive coupling. So for my money I would likely go with a typedeffed iterator.

Comment: @Galik: ...and in the end, I went with this. (Reader being an inner class of the Manager, being a template made such a mess of types I gave up on guessing which form of operator==() find() expects. (nope, not  `bool operator==(Reader& other) const`). Reader now contains an iterator pointing to own container, set upon creation and used upon destruction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your options if you only have a reference to the object is to use [`std::list::remove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove)

```
readers.remove(r);
```

or [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) in conjunction with `std::list::erase`

```
readers.erase(std::find(readers.begin(), readers.end(), r));
```

The former has to iterate the entire list while the latter will stop when it finds the first element and then removes it.  For large list this can make a big difference.

Both of these options only work when the items are unique.  If you have non unique elements then you can use `std::find_if` and provide a functor that compares the address of the items.  That way you can guarantee you only delete the object the reference actually refers to instead of compares equal to.

```
readers.erase(std::find_if(readers.begin(), readers.end(), [&](const auto& e) {return &r == &e;}));
```

Answer (score 4):

you can compare the pointers to check if they are same object

```
readers.remove_if([r=&r](auto& x){return &x==r;});
```

Comment: Remove expects a value it can compare to items in the list.  Pretty sure this wont compile

Comment: Maybe you mean `remove_if` and not `remove`?

Comment: Change `remove` to `remove_if` and you have the coolest solution!

Comment: Warning: remove_if will remove ALL elements that match the Predicate.

Comment: @nwfistere and the predicate here is comparing address (that is manage by the list), I'm not sure how can it match more than 1 element.

Comment: My warning was for general usage of remove_if, not this case.

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::remove` in combination with `erase`

```
readers.erase(std::remove(readers.begin(), readers.end(), r), readers.end());
```

Also, u can't delete element from list by value, without iterating it. If you think about it, it doesn't even make sense, because pointers inside the list **have to** be updated.

Comment: `remove` actually removes in this case.  This wont compile as it returns `void` due to that.

Comment: this will not find exactly this element, but any element which is equality comparable to it... You must compare the elems pointers...

Comment: @ovanes: since nobody cares about comparing readers in any other way than "is it the same instance?" this would be satisfactory.

Comment: @Sly_TheKing: Considering std::list is a doubly linked list, removing an element would be `this->previous->next = this->next; this->next->previous = this->previous; delete this;` there should be no need to search the list as long as you can access neighbors. But I bet  the base object doesn't hold these, the container does, and for that you need an iterator.

Comment: This still will not work.  `std::remove` does not remove anything from the container.

Comment: LOL, i was actually right first time... (tested it right now)

Comment: Oh, my bad.  I though you were using `list::remove` not `std::remove` the first go around.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @SF. that's exactly what i meant by pointers have to be updated, element that is stored doesn't have references to neighbouring objects. They are stored internally by container.

Comment: @NathanOliver no problem, i only changed my answer a couple of times :D

Answer (score 1):

If the list can contain equal values then you can do something like the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main()
{
    struct Reader { std::pair<char, int> p; };
    std::list<Reader> readers;

    readers.push_back({{ 'A', 1 } });
    readers.push_back({ { 'A', 2 } });
    Reader &rr = readers.back();
    readers.push_back({ { 'A', 3 } });

    readers.remove_if([&rr](const Reader &r) { return &r == &rr; });

    for (const auto &r : readers)
    {
        std::cout << r.p.first << ' ' << r.p.second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
A 1
A 3
```